# Динамический меню на Angular 7

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular-routing

Передо мной вот такая задача создать динамический меню на `Angular 7`. У меня вот такой `JSON`

```
{
  "menu": [
    {"id": "1", "parent_id": null, "url": "who-we-are", "desc": "Who we are"},
    {"id": "2", "parent_id": "1", "url": "our-mission", "desc": "Our mission"},
    {"id": "3", "parent_id": "1", "url": "our-history", "desc": "Our History"},
    {"id": "4", "parent_id": "1", "url": "leadership", "desc": "Leadership"},
    {"id": "5", "parent_id": "1", "url": "members", "desc": "Members"},
    {"id": "6", "parent_id": "1", "url": "join-aahpo", "desc": "Join AAHPO"},
    {"id": "7", "parent_id": "6", "url": "members", "desc": "Become a member"},
    {"id": "8", "parent_id": "6", "url": "renew-your-membership", "desc": "Renew your membership"},
    {"id": "9", "parent_id": "7", "url": "pay-your-dues", "desc": "Pay your dues"},
    {"id": "10", "parent_id": "8", "url": "renew-your-membership", "desc": "Pay your dues"},
    {"id": "11", "parent_id": "1", "url": "faqs", "desc": "FAQs"},
    {"id": "12", "parent_id": "1", "url": "contact-us", "desc": "Contact Us"},
    {"id": "13", "parent_id": "1", "url": "partnerships", "desc": "Partnerships"},
  ]
}
```

Обработаю его с помощью рекурсивной функции

```
menuPush(content, pid = null) {
    let menu = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
      if (content[i]['parent_id'] === pid) {
        menu.push({
          id: content[i]['id'],
          url: content[i]['url'],
          desc: content[i]['desc'],
          dropdown: this.menuPush(content, content[i]['id'])
        });
      }
    }
    return menu;
  }
```

А вот `html`

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
  <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"><a routerLink="/who-we-are">Who we are</a>
    <!--RD Navbar Dropdown-->
    <ul class="rd-navbar-dropdown">
      <li><a routerLink="/members">Members</a></li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="/join-aahpo">Join AAHPO</a>
        <!-- RD Navbar Dropdown -->
        <ul class="rd-navbar-dropdown">
          <li>
            <a routerLink="/become-a-member">Become a member</a>
            <ul class="rd-navbar-dropdown">
              <li>
                <a routerLink="/pay-your-dues">Pay your dues</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END RD Navbar Dropdown -->
      </li>
      <li><a routerLink="/partnerships">Partnerships</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--END RD Navbar Dropdown-->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Проблема в том что я не знаю сколько будет длина и сколько parent в одном меню. Можете помочь в написании.

Comment: Делаете компонент, который принимает на вход ваш массив. В компоненте рекурсивно вызываете этот же компонент, если есть `dropdown`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, да, это в действительности хорошее решение, только у него модель какая-то странная, вообще лучше б чтоб какое-то свойство `children` было

Comment: @overthesanity А оно есть, насколько я понимаю это `dropdown` и есть `children`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не, видите у него парент_ид есть, хотя по нормальному ребенок не должен указывать на родителя, а наоборот - только родитель должен указывать на ребенка

Comment: @overthesanity Это нормальная практика для реляционной БД держать ссылку на родителя. А потом уже как это использовать - вопрос другой. А почему по нормальному родитель должен на ребенка указывать? В чем преимущества?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну мы же не о рел. БД говорим щас :) потому что так легче всего отрендерить дерево компонентов, особенно в Angular с помощью байндингов и `ngIf` директивы, как вы это сделаете без указания на ребенка? (хотя бы абстрактно)

Comment: @overthesanity да, вы абсолютно правы. Для рендеринга в angular нужны дети. Ну он собственно их и создает, основываясь на `parent_id`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо идея хорошая. В материал ангулар тоже что то такого видел. Если не трудно можете отправить какую то ссылка с документацию или с примером. Опыт у меня не большой ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я набросал небольшой [пример](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zphyyg).

Самое главное что вам надо сделать, вызывать компонент внутри себя. Как рекурсия в функции - то же самое.

```
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menu">
    <li>{{item.desc}}</li>
    <li *ngIf="item.dropdown.length">
      <my-menu [menu]="item.dropdown"></my-menu>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: если можно еще один просьба, пример-https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncift тут при написании возникает проблема, когда вызываю `my-menu` класс первого `ul` добавляется и все структура сломается((( В примере показал как должен быть `html`

Comment: @AraChinaryan Ничего не понял. Что за *класс первого ul*?

Comment: @AraChinaryan я вангую, что вы хотите что-то вроде этого https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fb51hc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: простите что плохо объяснил да это хотел. Еще раз спасибо